# jMeter load testing with different load profiles

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

Our current load test for an application is done using jMeter and works fine so far. We have three different thread groups which can be enabled and configured separately via a command line flag. The number of threads and target throughput rate can be configured from the command line as well.

What I'm searching for is a possibility to program a load scenario for each of the thread groups.
Usually jMeter starts all threads and then tries reach its target throughput rate.
What I want to achieve is as follows: I configure a target throughput rate of 500 requests per second, a start rate of 20, an increment of 20 and a duration of 5 minutes.
jMeter should then start with 20 requests per second and increase the load by 20 every 5 minutes until it reaches the maximum throughput rate.

Has anyone ever done this? I searched for it but didn't find any relevant hits.

Comment: [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/) available via JMeter [Plugin Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

Answer (score 1):

I think [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) is what you're looking for as there is no way of mapping number of virtual users to number of desired transactions per second:

[image: Concurrency Thread Group]

The easiest way to install this and other custom Thread Groups provided via [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) project is using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image: JMeter Plugins Manager]

Comment: That heads in a really good direction. Thanks.
Now what I need is unfortunately not a limit in number of users (expressed by threads) but in number of transactions per second.
I'm testing a Webservice which has to handle a lot of requests during peak phases within a certain response time and I need to see until which point the service is able to handle requests in a timely manner.

Comment: Nevermind. I found the Throughput Shaping Timer which does nearly what I need. Some tweaks required, though.
https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/

Answer (score 0):

Besides the already mentioned Concurrency Thread Group there is also a Throughput Shaping Timer which allows to configure load shapes.
https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/